# What is the difference between run project and run file on netbeans ide 7.3?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I was working on a JApplet program, then i pressed the hot key, F6 ( run project). It gave me an error, then i pressed Shift + F6 ( run File), which worked. So my question is, what is the difference between  run project and run file on netbeans ide 7.3?

This is the code i was using.

```
package javaapplication128;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class JavaApplication128 extends JApplet {

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString("hello", 25, 25);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Run File command when I want to run only one, particular file, not an entire project. I find it useful when, for example, I create a class with JDialog. To see this Dialog (without running an entire project) I can add a `public static void main()` inside my class in which I create an instance of my dialog and I can see how does it look like.

Example:

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog{
    public void createAndShow(){
        setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setVisible(true);
        // some other stuff, initializing components etc..
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog.createAndShow();
    }
}
```

To see how this dialog looks like, I do not have to run the entire project. I can simply Run this file (Shitf+F6)

Comment: So its better to use shift + F6?

Comment: If you have a big project which need a few minutes to run... definitely yes ; )